# GrandParent ,Parent, Child issue

Tags: theme-development

I have the following

```
GrandParent
-Parent01
--Child
-Parent02
--Child
--Child
-Parent03
--Child
```

I wish to find a solution that when Im on the Grandparent page, that it will only return the parents and not the children IE.

```
GrandParent
-Parent01
-Parent02
-Parent03
```

This is the code I have at present, and it produces all parents and children of the grandparent page, and places them into a table.

```
<?php $postid = get_the_ID(); ?> 
<?php /* $pages = get_pages(array('child_of' =>$postid)); */
$pages = get_children(array(
 'numberposts' =>30,
'post_parent' => $heading_page->post_id
 ));
$tCount= 0;
?> 
<table align="center" width="100%"><tr>
<?php foreach ($pages as $page): ?>
<?php     if($tCount % 2 == 0) 
{
    echo '</tr><tr>';
}?>
<td>  
<div id="polaroid">  
<figure>
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($page->ID); ?>">
        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, array(300,250)); ?></a>
    <figcaption>   
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($page->ID); ?>"><?php echo $page-   >post_title ?>
</a></figcaption>
</figure>
</div>  
 </td> 
<?php $tCount++; endforeach; ?>
</tr></table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24847487/1908141) on Stack overflow fixed it for me ... by adding in these lines ..

```
<?php foreach ( $pages as $page ): ?>
<?php if ( $postid != $page->post_parent ) continue; ?>
```

Comment: :-) thanks... thanks for the edits, you beat me to it !!

Comment: Pleasure, was actually busy reading your question on SO when you posted the answer. Enjoy

Comment: What I forgot to say, you should take @TomJNowell Other Notes into consideration when you write code. That is very important

Answer (score 1):

You're using `get_children` and it's doing exactly what you told it to do. You told it to get all the descendants of that post, and thats what you got. You need to be more specific about what you're querying for, that you only want immediate descendants.

You almost had the right idea originally:

```
$pages = get_pages(array('child_of' => $postid ));
```

But there is no `child_of` parameter according to the `WP_Query` documentation. So instead of asking for a posts children, ask for posts with a parent of `$postid`, giving us:

```
$pages = get_posts(array(
    'post_parent' => $postid,
    'post_type' => 'page'
));
```

Other notes:

- Use a grid system or left floated divs instead of a table, it's more flexible and you can remove your counting logic making your loop much simpler
- ***Indent your code***, indented code is easier to read, makes an entire class of errors obvious, and makes it easier for people to understand your code and write answers to your questions
- Use `foreach () {}` rather than `foreach(): endforeach;`, it works better with editors and automated tools and checkers.
- Only put 1 command per line
- All your divs have an ID of polaroid, but IDs are meant to be unique, use a class instead

Comment: No that dosent do the job for me

Comment: +1 for the "Other Notes". I actually use `foreach(): endforeach;` a lot. Never actually took what you've mentioned about this into consideration.

Comment: @Nemothefish exactly what did it do? How was it different to what you're trying to do? I can't help you if all I have is "it doesn't work", I need more detail, a lot more

Comment: @TomJNowell, I was looking for a way of getting back only the parents from a list of Grandparent, parent and child, my original code was returning parent and child. I have found a way as posted bellow, by checking to see if the returned result is a parent or not, Im probably not explaining this very well.

Comment: Try the adjusted code with `get_posts` rather than `get_pages`

Comment: Just as a note, `get_children` is pretty much just a wrapper for `get_posts`, so it should work likewise. Besides it does **not** get all descendants, but nomen est omen the children. The latter is the case if a `$post_id` is given for the `post_parent` parameter. Otherwise the default value for `post_parent` is `0` which gives back `any` - default for `post_type` - post *without* a parent. If `null` is given as value for `post_parent` any child of any parent will be returned.